# Unable to serve app after successfully adding cordova-plugin-contacts

Tags: ios, cordova, mobile, hybrid

I am trying to use the cordova-plugin-contacts in a hybrid mobile app. I am using xcode and iOS simulator to run the app. 
There is no error seen on executing the cordova plugin add command. However when I build and serve the app, I see a bunch of deprecation warnings for AddressBook starting from iOS 9. I am currently on xcode version 10.
Is there a way to fix this issue? If not, what all the alternate plugins that could be used?

I see warnings similar to this:

```
In module 'AddressBook' imported from <path/Cordova-plugin- 
contacts/CDVContact.h> note: 'ABMultiValueCreateMutableCopy'
has been explicitly marked deprecated here 
AB_EXTERNABMutableMultiValueRef 
ABMultiValueCreateMutableCopy(ABMultiValueRef multiValue) 
AB_DEPRECATED("use [NSArray mutableCopy]");
```